# SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.imdb.com:443

Tags: r, github

I have an issue in R with the following code

```r
link <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=action&sort=user_rating,desc&title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,&pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=5aab685f-35eb-40f3-95f7-c53f09d542c3&pf_rd_r=6MXX0DJX50KBH1680T3M&pf_rd_s=right-6&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_gnr_1"
   
main <- read_html(link)
```

It tells me

```r
#Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
#  LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to #www.imdb.com:443
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59688838/3358272, especially because on IMDB's [Conditions of Use](https://www.imdb.com/conditions), they expressly say *"Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below."* I know this type of discouragement is often glossed-over or dismissed in the sake of "academic pursuit", please be mindful. (FYI, they seem amenable to permitting for personal use, read that doc and it says how to get permission.)

Comment: Try using `imdbapi` or `omdbapi` library.